# django simple ratings, too much query

Tags: python, django, django-ratings

I'm using [django-simple-ratings](https://github.com/coleifer/django-simple-ratings) on my project. I hook the `ratings` to my `Post` app, so users can vote up/down and then order it by  the score. Pretty much what i want is included on the `ratings` app. There's this page where i need to list all of the `Post` (just like stackoverflow). But for every `post` in `Post` where i display the ratings, it hit the db, and it makes the site reeeaaall slow. models.py:

```
from ratings.models import Ratings, RatedItemBase

class PostRatings(RatedItemBase):

    content_object = models.ForeignKey('Post')

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    content = models.TextField()
    ratings = Ratings(PostRatings)

for q in Post.objects.all():
    print q.ratings.cumulative_score()
    #or
    print q.postratings_set.aggregate(Sum('score'))['score__sum']
```

For every loop, it hit the db, another try:

```
for q in Post.objects.prefetch_related('postratings_set'):
    print q.postratings_set.aggregate(Sum('score'))['score__sum']
```

Still hit the db for every loop.

Does any of you have the same problem? How did you solved it? Or should i change to another ratings app? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there might be `JOIN` type queries with the absence of proper indexes. But you need to post or inspect what queries are actually getting executed by Django ORM. Only then can there a solution emerge for optimization. For this there is a perfect tool [`Django-debug`](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar).

After installing this app, you can use `debugsqlshell`. Running your models in this mode outputs the SQL that gets executed as you work in the Python interactive shell. For Example -

```
$ ./manage.py debugsqlshell
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:51)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from page.models import Page
>>> ### Lookup and use resulting in an extra query...
>>> p = Page.objects.get(pk=1)
SELECT "page_page"."id",
       "page_page"."number",
       "page_page"."template_id",
       "page_page"."description"
FROM "page_page"
WHERE "page_page"."id" = 1
```

Hope this helps...